# Python equivalent of Pulse Integration (pulsint) MATLAB function?

Tags: python-3.x, matlab, signal-processing

I am surfing online to find Python equivalent of function [pulsint](https://de.mathworks.com/help/phased/ref/pulsint.html) of MATLAB , and till now I haven't found anything significantly close to it.

Any heads up in this regards will be really helpful!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily create your own pulsint function.

The pulsint formula:

[image]

You need the numpy library to keep the things simple

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib as mpl

# Non coherent integration
def pulsint(x):
    return np.sqrt(np.sum(np.power(np.absolute(x),2),0)) 

npulse = 10;

# Random data (100x10 vector)
x = np.matlib.repmat(np.sin(2*np.pi*np.arange(0,100)/100),npulse,1)+0.1*np.random.randn(npulse,100)

# Plot the result
mpl.pyplot.plot(pulsint(x))
mpl.pyplot.ylabel('Magnitude')
```

[image]

Comment: Impressive!! I was about to do that!!